# Android-World Clock Widget analog

Tags: android, widget, clock

I am planning to create a world clock widget in android. The clock should show the selected country's time as an analog clock widget. But I'm feeling difficulties as I'm a beginner in android.

My widget.xml file contains the following:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  android:id="@+id/Widget"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_margin="8dip"
  android:background="@drawable/myshape" >
<AnalogClock android:id="@+id/AnalogClock"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:dial="@drawable/widgetdial" 
 android:hand_hour="@drawable/widgethour"
 android:hand_minute="@drawable/widgetminute"/>
```

I am using the following configuration activity for my widget:-
(To display the city list)
package nEx.Software.Tutorials.Widgets.AnalogClock;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AnalogClock;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
public class ConfigureApp extends Activity {
DateFormat df;
 private ListView cityList;

    public static String[][] citylist = new String[1242][10];
    String[] cities = new String[1242];
    String field[] = new String[20];
    String list[][] = new String[1242][10];                         
    String country = "";
    String line = null;
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    // Variables for list view population
    String city = "";
    int position = 0;
    public int[] listArray = new int[1242];
    public static int len = 0;
    public String[][] adapterCityList = new String[1242][3];
    // Variables for passing intent data 
    public static final String citieslist = "com.world.citieslist";
   AppWidgetManager awm;
   Context c;
   int awID;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        // Set the result to CANCELED.  This will cause the widget host to cancel
        // out of the widget placement if they press the back button.
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
          try {
              citylist = getCityList();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              Log.e("Loading CityList", e.getMessage());
          }

          for (int i = 0; i < 1242; i++) {
              cities[i] = citylist[i][0];
          }
        // Set the view layout resource to use.
        setContentView(R.layout.configure);
    c = ConfigureApp.this;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
          awID = extras.getInt(
        AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 
        AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
   } else{
finish();
}

awm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(c);



        cityList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.CityList);
     // By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.
     cityList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cities));
    // cityList.setOnItemClickListener(cityListListener);
          cityList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
                df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                  String str = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();

                  RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(),
                        R.layout.widget);
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.mytext, str);
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.date, df.format(new Date()));
                 Intent in = new Intent(c,clock.class);

                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, in, 0);
                remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Widget, pi);
                                    awm.updateAppWidget(awID, remoteViews);
                    Intent result = new Intent();
                result.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,awID);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
                finish();

            }
        });
    }           
    private String[][] getCityList() throws IOException {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        InputStream instream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cities_final);

        // if file the available for reading
        if (instream != null) {

            // prepare the file for reading
            InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

            while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {

                field = line.split(",");
                for (String x : field) {
                    list[row][col] = x;
                    col++;
                    if (x != null) {
                        country = x;
                    }
                }
                list[row][2] = country;
                row++;
                col = 0;
            }

            for (int i = 0; (i < list.length); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; (j < 3); j++) {
                    if (j == 1) {
                        list[i][j] = list[i][j].substring(0, 6);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

}

Can I use my own custom view in the widget, apart from analog clock? Or is there any other way to show the clock? like use the Imageview as the clock face and to draw the dial according to the time?

Please help me regarding this.!!!:(

Answer (score 0):

A similar example for thermometer is given in this link 
http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/
You can create your own view and make the clock as well.

Comment: I am unable to display my custom view in the home screen as widget it is showing "Problem loading widget". This example is working in case of an activity only, not in the case of the AppWidgetProvider. Please suggest me with some working example :(

Answer (score 0):

You can replaced the clock dial, clock hand minute and clock hand hour with your own drawings. Then You'll have your own custom clock.

```
 android:dial="@drawable/YOUR_OWN_DIAL" 
 android:hand_hour="@drawable/YOUR_OWN_HOUR"
 android:hand_minute="@drawable/YOUR_OWN_MINUTE"
```

Test the layout in the Graphical Layout Tool to see how it look like.